Unity HDRP - после примерно 30 лампочек некоторые перестают работать и возле них артефакты
Делаю игру на Unity с HDRP про закулисье там требуется очень много источников света. Но когда я делаю примерно 30 штук то некоторые лампочки перестают работать и возле них артефакты в виде черных пикселей которые мерцают очень не приятно.


Самый простой и очевидный способ решения проблемы - перестать использовать большое количество источников света.
Но как быть с созданием сеттинга? Один из вариантов решения проблемы использовать HDRP освещение при этом установить 2-3 источника света, а светильники сделать не источником света, а при помощи имитации свечения - light emission у материала.
Выглядит это так:


Как это устроено - на сцене есть 2-3 источника света которые имитируют освещение от псевдо-светильников:

Что бы создать имитацию источников света используем light emission у материала:

Таким не хитрым образом можно создать очень много эффектов освещения без использования огромного количества источников света.
Но есть и минусы - нет отражений от псевдо-светильников - менее реалистично. Похожий light emission есть и у URP освещения.

оффтоп:
Обрати внимание, что на твой вопрос никто не хочет отвечать. Почему так происходит? Ты не указал абсолютно никакой информации о своём проекте, какой используешь рендер SRP, URP, HDRP, типы источников света, версия Unity и т.д. При твоих вводных очень сложно дать хороший совет даже если очень захочешь.
Вообще в таких случаях самый хороший вариант упаковать свой проект и выгрузить его в облако, маил, яндекс, гугл - не важно. Куда проще тебе помочь открыв твой проект и самостоятельно с ним взаимодействуя. Скачать, запустить и посмотреть куда проще, чем гадать.
Можешь попробовать загрузить свой проект, и я посмотрю что можно сделать.

использование light emission
Unity HDRP

Да можем попробовать но правда проект весит примерно 1 гигабайт (Я сделал новый проект который использует релиз UNITY 6) и да я проверял эта проблема только у меня, у моих знакомых все хорошо на HDRP со светом. Мне скорее нужна не имитация света а сам свет. Мои годадки что это Кэш освещения на движке , так как у меня юнити скачен уже около 2-ух лет.

Ну 1gb это ещё семечки. У меня от 20gb проекты. Скинь на любое удобное облако, будем посмотреть.
